# Do \parencite{<key>} and (\cite{<key>}) produce the same?

Tags: biblatex, citing

Are they the same?

```
\usepackage{biblatex}

testing123 \parencite{Author1} testing123 
testing123 (\cite{Author1}) testing123
```

I just want to have

> (Author1, 2001)

When I compiled my document the outcome is same.

Comment: From page 100 of the biblatex manual: "\parencite These commands use a format similar to \cite but enclose the entire citation
in parentheses." So, basically (\cite) and \parencite produce the same output. However, the latter is especially useful if you later on decide Tha you would like to replace () around citations with [] or something else.

Comment: @leandriis, thanks. I just worry it will have a different output in term of cross-referencing for `\parencite` and `(\cite)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, in general we can't say that

```
(\cite{sigfridsson})
```

and

```
\parencite{sigfridsson}
```

give the same result. For many styles the result is the same, since `\parencite` is intended to produce parenthetical citations or at least citations in some kind of brackets, but this is nothing we can rely on.

For example

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
(\cite{sigfridsson})

\parencite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

produces

> ([1])
>
> [1]

But even for `authoryear`-type styles, where `\cite` doesn't come with parentheses of its own the output may be different. APA style, for example, requires that citation in parentheses be typeset different than other citations. With `\parencite` `biblatex` knows about the parentheses and can adjust accordingly, with `(\cite{...})` not so much.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
(\cite{sigfridsson})

\parencite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> (Sigfridsson and Ryde, 1998)
>
> (Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998)

There could be other more complex examples where `\cite` typeset additional brackets and `(\cite{...})` and `\parencite{...}` would result in nested brackets. In that case `\parencite` will switch the types of brackets between round and square brackets to make it easier to spot the nesting level, but `(\cite{...})` won't do that as the parentheses are invisible to `biblatex`.

**I *strongly* recommend you use `\parencite` over `(\cite{...})`** since it is the semantically more meaningful command and *knows* about the parentheses. `\parencite` makes it easier to switch styles without bad side-effects.

**I would even go further and recommend `\autocite`**

```
\autocite{sigfridsson}
```

With `authoryear`-like styles `\autocite` usually behaves like `\parencite`, but its behaviour can be customised with the `autocite` option and switching styles becomes even easier, because you can just say `autocite=footnote,` to get footnote citations.